# java.lang.StackOverflowError but i'm not looping anything

Tags: java, javafx, stack-overflow

I have two methods one in the main class and one in a class called 'DeleteWall' .I'm creating instances of each class so I can access their methods .I've read all the posts on stackOverflows but I don't see what i'm doing wrong ...like i'm not looping it to make a new instance as far as I  can see anyway.I'll highlight the lines which are causing the errors as intellij says.I'm only calling demo once aswell
.Oh and the method 'delNode' is in the main class hence the instance of it 'werk'.

```
    //Main class
    DeleteWall ok=new DeleteWall(); //error line
    public void demo(){
    System.out.println("running");
    ok.delWalls(30,0,30,30);
    System.out.println("didnt stop");
    }
     //DeleteWall class
     public class DeleteWall  {

     Main werk = new Main(); //error line

     public  void delWalls(int Sx, int Sy, int Ex, int Ey) {


     werk.delNode(Sx, Sy, Ex, Ey);
     }

     }
```

the error
[image]

Comment: In your main class, a `DeleteWall` instance is created, which in turn creates a `Main` instance, which in turn creates a `DeleteWall` instance, which in turn ... well, you get the idea.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023090/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-but-im-not-looping-anything

Comment: yeEEEE there's no question quite like mine

Comment: @khelwood Indeed, perhaps this will give a rough idea of recursion.

Comment: @MCEmperor Oh right. Whoosh.

Comment: Ohhh I get it haha 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is reduced to

```
public class Main {
    DeleteWall ok = new DeleteWall();
}
```

and

```
public class DeleteWall  {
    Main werk = new Main();
}
```

if any of these class gets instantiated, an instance of the other must be created which in turn will again create a **new** instance of first, and so on.
The whole design is *strange*, like declaring that each House always contains a Car and each Car always contains a House.

Solving the problem: have the `DeleteWall` receive the instance of `Main` instead of creating a new one. Some possibilities:

- in the constructor

  ```
  public class Main {
      DeleteWall ok = new DeleteWall(this);
  }

  ////

  public class DeleteWall  {
      Main werk;
      public DeleteWall(Main main) {
          werk = main;
      }
  }
  ```
- when calling

  ```
  public class Main {
      DeleteWall ok = new DeleteWall();
      public void demo() {
          ok.delWalls(this, 30, 0, 30, 30);
      }
  }

  ////

  public class DeleteWall  {
      public void delWalls(Main werk, ...) {
          werk.delNodes(...);
      }
  }
  ```

(there are many other possibilities, it depends heavily on what the program should do, how the problem is modeled, preferences, ...)

Comment: ayy Carlos coming throughhhhhh, thanks alot man. It works now ,Doing my dance moves to celebrate

Answer (score 3):

You have an instance of `DeleteWall` inside `Main` and and instance of `Main` inside `DeleteWall`. Now when it tries to create the `Main` class it will need to create an `DeleteWall` instance for the field `DeleteWall ok= new DeleteWall();` when it tries to do that, it will need to create an instance of `Main` for the field `Main werk = new Main();` inside `DeleteWall`. Then it goes back to create Main and there you have your infinite loop.

Comment: Ok yeah I sorta get what your saying . What's the convention for calling methods from other classes then? cheerzzz

Comment: You can just create an instance of the other class in a non-static method and call the method on that instance

Comment: so like  , public happy void(){ Main werk = new Main();} ?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: okkkkk but then where do I call that method?

Comment: Like you already have: `werk.delNode(Sx, Sy, Ex, Ey);`
Just move `Main werk = new Main(); //error line`
Inside the method below (where you use it) that will fix it

Answer (score 1):

Your `Main` class has a field `ok` which is initialized with a `DeleteWall` object. Your `DeleteWall` class has a field `werk` which is initialized with a `Main` object.

So, when the program starts running, it instantiates the `Main` class. Since all fields are assigned their default values when the class is instantiated, this needs to instantiate the `DeleteWall` class, so that `werk` can be initialized. Instantiating the `DeleteWall` class needs to instantiate the `Main` class, so that `ok` can be initialized. Instantiating the `Main` class needs to instantiate the `DeleteWall` class, so that `werk` can be initialized. Instantiating the `DeleteWall` class needs to instantiate the `Main` class, so that `ok` can be initialized. Instantiating the `Main` class needs to instantiate the `DeleteWall` class, so that `werk` can be initialized.
...